# Typescript type composition via Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm struggling to keep my dynamically generated types (via generics) after a few usage in a factory. An example explains better than words: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwK4BsCGAnAIm4aoC8UA3gL4DcAUAPTUCCUAtoqtAFZIDOwUAFnCgRQEuNJVCRYLFBAA8WKBAAewCADsEnKcnTZRAPkIlKUYaIBcULFQqVKAMyRqAxsACWcNU2kQAYmlc4DBB5fQAKETxLLABKS3gdOSxDYhMoDAhgJAwvYjM8KFtSO1oACQgMqGBeNy1aqEgMewhXABpFAN4oADdMNzQAIxk+NC1nGUwq8AhOSmdPbm8EAEYjZkT-QOCwvIz7SwAGQpiqebVF9YAmNZ9N4CCQHag4aoqAJQh9qGXLgGZjqjiaZQADCcEYYDgnAgCASrFkIMMRDhMgR+gA2gBdKi0AAKGBYrig9XmEKhMOe9iYqHcYGG61Yswk0HxhOAaKMqVMDJknEsYLJ0NhPjRNiojhc7k8DQJyFcdweaLCPJmABlasB+eDIUKUXJEXEoKy5ezEcZTBksjlzaYlozLCrOOruK00kUStQoAAVGpaTj8VBCNQvKD2NyVNBeCoEjBQSNCfjdCrPLxhtRoFBQf1wQNQFAauMoTMozA4ArVXBQUk66CvUNudOZ41IVxzBY8NMZoxgWUt4AK7bo9bLdpXTEnGiegCSUAA7pGePcoANoINhkvoaukPdqzIpV5eBVVxooMGO+HjyBFBgY7NOygAHSO9EHTEPyJoB97Iy-cUNjNPj4nDossb4fg+LyHhgHxUkQACs5BAA)

```js
type ModularData = {};
//A module just hold data
type Module<D extends ModularData> = {
  data: D;
};

function moduleFactory<D>(data: D): Module<D> {
  return { data };
}

//Here this is perfect, each variable has clear types
const mod1 = moduleFactory({ ref: 0 });
const mod2 = moduleFactory({ otherRef: 123 });

type ComposedModule<C> = Module<C>[];
//Product is composed of multiple modules
type Product<C> = {
  modules: ComposedModule<C>;
};
function productFactory<C>(modulesList: ComposedModule<C>): Product<C> {
  return {
    modules: modulesList,
  };
}

// This should not fire an error and hover on final should list all ModularData that compose the final Product
const final = productFactory([mod1, mod2]);
// I want to be able to see autocompletion here and not fire any errors
final.modules[0].data.ref = 3;
final.modules[1].data.otherRef = 5;
```

Note that the data in modules can be anything. I've tried so many things, I can't find a way around.

Thanks!

Comment: please always include your code into question

Comment: That's because you typed `ComposedModule` with a single generic type `C` so once `C` has been inferred from the function call, the `modulesList` parameter is expected to be of that type only but it finds other types in the array

Comment: I can leave a more detailed answer later, but I would say that the issue is here `type ComposedModule<C> = Module<C>[];` where you are saying that all modules in the array have the same type, rather than allowing it to be a tuple with varying types.  You’ll want to use a generic to refer to the type of the entire tuple rather than to the type of the data property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current type setup assumes that all modules in the list have the same data type `C`:

```
type ComposedModule<C> = Module<C>[];
```

The generic `C` could be a union of the two types, but that still would not allow you to access `.ref` on one and `.otherRef` on the other.  What you really want is to know that the first item has data type `{ref: number}` and the second has data type `{otherRef: number}`.

To do this, the generic on your `propertyFactory` function describe the entire array as a tuple.

We want something like this:

```
function productFactory<List>(modulesList: List): {modules: List} {
```

But we also want to enforce that the `List` generic must be an array which contains `Module` objects.  We do that using `extends`.

The last bit of annoyingness here involves `readonly` and `as const`.  By default, your array `[mod1, mod2]` gets interpreted as an array of any length whose elements can be either `{ref: number}` or `{otherRef: number}`.  But your last two lines require a more specific type.  We need to know specific type based on the array index.  In order to interpret the argument as a typed tuple, you need to use `[mod1, mod2] as const`.  Using `as const` also means that the function must allow for `readonly` arrays.

```
type Product<List> = { // or <List extends readonly Module<any>[]>
  modules: List;
};

function productFactory<List extends readonly Module<any>[]>(modulesList: List): Product<List> {
  return {
    modules: modulesList,
  };
}

// final has type Product<readonly [Module<{ref: number;}>, Module<{otherRef: number;}>]>
const final = productFactory([mod1, mod2] as const);

// data has type {ref: number}
final.modules[0].data.ref = 3;

// data has type {otherRef: number}
final.modules[1].data.otherRef = 5;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w2E9zW)

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 problems:

1. In this piece of code you are directly inserting the object without specifying that you have a **common interface (type)**. Create a type for each object and then create a common type.

```
interface A {
  ref: number
}

interface B {
  otherRef: number
}

type AB = A | B;

//Now the error will disappear. Since you omitted the type of your array, typescript inferred the type of the first object
const final = productFactory<AB>([mod1, mod2]);
```

2. When you use a shared interface, **before accessing interface-specific fields you have to verify that the object belongs to that interface**. To do this type of evaluation I like to insert a common field in interfaces that can be evaluated. Something like:

```
interface A {
  type: 'A' //Notice, enums are cleaner to do this kind of things
  ref: number
}

interface B {
  type: 'B'
  otherRef: number
}

const mod1 = moduleFactory({ type: 'A' as 'A', ref: 0 });
const mod2 = moduleFactory({ type: 'B' as 'B', otherRef: 123 });

const final = productFactory<AB>([mod1, mod2]);

//Access ref:
let refObject = final.modules[0].data;
if(refObject.type === 'A'){
 //Now you can access the object
 refObject.ref = 3;
}
```